# How can I run my app after doing a signingReport?

Tags: android-studio

I did a signing report to get the SHA1 of the project by double-clicking signingReport in the Gradle panel under root->Tasks->Android->signingReport.

Now when I try to run my app in the emulator from the run menu (Shift+F10) the button shows **Run 'app [signingReport]'**, and only does another signing report.

How can I undo what I've done, and what should it be set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change the `configuration` to run. You can see a drop down near the run button. Select `app` in that and it will run the app. Here is a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXHEi.png).